# Does eax always, and only, store the system call?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm, cpu-registers

[I'm confused about the CPU registers and I haven't found any truly clear and coherent explanation of them across the whole internet. If anyone has a link to something useful I'd really appreciate it if you'd post it in a comment or answer.]

The primary reason I'm here now is because I have been looking at sample NASM programs in a [thus far vain] attempt to learn the language. The program always ends by placing a system call code in `eax` and then calling `int 0x80` (which I would love if someone could explain as well). However, from what I understand, `eax` is a 32 bit register - why do you need 32 bits to store system calls (I'm sure there aren't 2<sup>32</sup> worth). Also, sometimes I see other values and strings moved into eax during the program itself. Does that mean `eax` only has a special use when you finally want to perform a system call but for the rest of the time you can do with it as you please?

Comment: Read http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch What is useful at this link?

Comment: In Linux on i?86, system calls _used_ to be called by stashing the call number in eax and causing an interrupt 0x80. Windows does it differently, current Linux uses the sysenter instruction. So this is intimately operating system related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All bits of `eax` are used because that's how the system call interface is implemented. It's true there aren't 2<sup>32</sup> system calls, not even 2<sup>16</sup>. But that's how it is. It allows for easy extension of the set of the system calls. You don't need to think hard about it, just accept it as a fact and live on.

`eax` is a general purpose register and you can do with it anything you please. The fact that it's used to contain the system call ID is just an established convention and nothing else. `eax` is not anyhow forbidden for other uses.

Comment: But I'm bothered by why we need such a large register to store system calls, why can't there be a special 8 bit system call register?

Comment: The 80386 CPU appeared long before Linux, in 1986, so the CPU couldn't "know" about Linux and reserve a special register for it. Further, parameters are typically passed as an integral number of machine words (in the registers or on the stack) and truncating and zero-extending an 8-bit integer multiple times in the process of handling of system call requests is probably a not a very reasonable thing to do (you'd need more instructions and CPU cycles for that). Think about it... If the system call ID is used to index a table containing pointers to functions, the index has to be 32-bit anyway.

Comment: ...the index has to be 32-bit because the CPU does not support accessing memory operands indirectly using 8-bit registers, e.g. `AL`. It does support 16-bit registers here, but the resulting address is then limited to 16 bits that limits the location of the table of pointers to only the lower 64K of the address space, and yet you have 4G of it in 32-bit mode. So, 32-bit registers are a natural choice.

Answer (score 2):

> The program always ends by placing a system call code in eax and then calling int 0x80 (which I would love if someone could explain as well).

This is because you're only looking at old 32-bit examples for Linux, and that is what the Linux developers felt like doing. There's no reason why they couldn't have used a different register, and not much reason they couldn't have used half a register (e.g. a `ax` instead of `eax`, or `bx` or ..). In a similar way, there's no reason they couldn't have used a call gate or a different interrupt number. Of course once Linux developers made their decision ("kernel will expect function number in EAX and use int 0x80") everything that calls their kernel has to comply with their decision; and they can't easily change their decision without breaking all existing software (but can, and did, support alternatives - e.g. adding support for `sysenter` and `syscall` when those instructions got invented, while ensuring that `int 0x80` still works the same).

> However, from what I understand, eax is a 32 bit register - why do you need 32 bits to store system calls (I'm sure there aren't 232 worth)

They didn't "need" 32-bits; but you can expect that the function number will (after a "is the value too big" sanity check) end up being used inside a `call [table+eax*4]` instruction to call the selected function, and because that uses 32-bit addressing it needs to use a 32-bit register. Using half (or a quarter) of a register would've involved zero extension (e.g. an extra `and eax,0x0000FFFF` or `movzx eax,ax` instruction) to convert the 16-bit value into a 32-bit value. It's also typically faster to use all 32 bits for other reasons (e.g. a `mov ax,123` that sets the lowest 16 bits of EAX and leaves the highest 16 bits unchanged will depend on the previous value of the highest 16 bits, and that can cause a "dependency stall" in the CPU if it needs to wait until the previous value of EAX is known).

> Does that mean eax only has a special use when you finally want to perform a system call but for the rest of the time you can do with it as you please?

It means that when you call someone else's code, you have to comply with someone else's calling conventions, regardless of what they are. This can mean using other registers (`ebx`, `ecx`, etc) for whatever purpose they decided, and can mean using a specific stack layout (e.g. pushing things onto stack in a specific order).

Note that there are various instructions that do expect specific registers to be used in a specific way - `mul`, `div`, `stosd`, `movsd`, `loop`, `in`, `out`, `enter`, `leave`, etc; and there are "rare special cases" for every general purpose register. Despite this; they are still "general purpose registers" because they are not "specific purpose registers" (like `eip` or flags, which can only be used for one specific purpose and can never be used for anything else).

Answer (score 1):

eax is a general purpose register, you can put whatever you want in it.  int 0x80 is the interrupt for a system call... that interrupt looks at the value in eax and calls that system routine.